# Image Mime type is not being redirected to Save/Open dialog box

Tags: java, rest, extjs, extjs3

I am using Rest-API along with Extjs, i have a link to download file types in my application, if the file type is doc or xls, other than Image(Image/jpeg mime-type) i wil get Save/Open dialog box, But for Image(Image/jpeg mime-type) i am not getting dialog box.

Please help me out in solving this issue

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Try setting Content-Disposition header on server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried like this it worked.

```
     httpResponse.setContentType("application/x-download");
     httpResponse.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
```